# "Загружается начальный виртуальный диск …" бесконечно с linux 5.10.16

Tags: linux

Поставил убунту рядом с виндой. Решил попробовать пересобрать ядро. Рабочая версия ядра - '5.8.0-43-generic', новое - '5.10.16'. Скопировал файл моей конфигурации в дерево исходников. Все успешно "мэйкнул" по мануалу (https://wiki.merionet.ru/servernye-resheniya/77/poshagovoe-rukovodstvo-kak-sobrat-yadro-linux-s-nulya/). При перезагрузки и загрузки с нового ядра загрузка останавливается на "Загружается Linux 5.8.0-43-generic … Загружается начальный виртуальный диск …". В чем может быть проблема? Я подумал, что возможно ошибка в конфигурации: вот все различия в файлах /boot/config-5.8.0-43-generic и /boot/config-5.10.16:

```
lines in config-5-8 that differ from config-5-10:
config-5-8: CONFIG_VERSION_SIGNATURE="Ubuntu 5.8.0-43.49~20.04.1-generic 5.8.18", config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_TASKS_RCU=y, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_DPTF_POWER=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_ONDEMAND=y, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_CC_HAS_STACKPROTECTOR_NONE=y, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_HAVE_COPY_THREAD_TLS=y, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_HAVE_MEMORY_PRESENT=y, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_INTEL_MIC_BUS=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SCIF_BUS=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_VOP_BUS=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_INTEL_MIC_HOST=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_INTEL_MIC_CARD=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SCIF=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_MIC_COSM=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_VOP=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_BCACHE_ASYNC_REGISTRAION=y, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_CAIF_SPI_SLAVE=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_MSCC_OCELOT_SWITCH=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_MDIO_XPCS=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_PINCTRL_INTEL=m, config-5-10: CONFIG_PINCTRL_INTEL=y
config-5-8: CONFIG_POWER_AVS=y, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_QCOM_CPR=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_MFD_SMSC=y, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_BACKLIGHT_GENERIC=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SND_SST_IPC=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SND_SST_IPC_PCI=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SND_SST_IPC_ACPI=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SND_SOC_INTEL_SST_ACPI=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SND_SOC_INTEL_SST_FIRMWARE=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SND_SOC_INTEL_HASWELL=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SND_SOC_INTEL_HASWELL_MACH=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SND_SOC_INTEL_BDW_RT5650_MACH=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SND_SOC_INTEL_BDW_RT5677_MACH=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SND_SOC_INTEL_BROADWELL_MACH=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SND_SOC_RT5677=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SND_SOC_RT5677_SPI=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_USB_BDC_PCI=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_USB_ROLE_SWITCH=m, config-5-10: CONFIG_USB_ROLE_SWITCH=y
config-5-8: CONFIG_LEDS_LP55XX_COMMON=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_LEDS_LP5521=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_LEDS_LP5523=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_LEDS_LP5562=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_LEDS_LP8501=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_INTEL_MIC_X100_DMA=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SPEAKUP=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SPEAKUP_SYNTH_ACNTSA=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SPEAKUP_SYNTH_APOLLO=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SPEAKUP_SYNTH_AUDPTR=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SPEAKUP_SYNTH_BNS=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SPEAKUP_SYNTH_DECTLK=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SPEAKUP_SYNTH_DECEXT=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SPEAKUP_SYNTH_LTLK=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SPEAKUP_SYNTH_SOFT=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SPEAKUP_SYNTH_SPKOUT=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SPEAKUP_SYNTH_TXPRT=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SPEAKUP_SYNTH_DUMMY=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_VIDEO_USBVISION=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_ASHMEM=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_MOST_USB=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_DELL_UART_BACKLIGHT=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_MFD_CROS_EC=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_PHY_INTEL_EMMC=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_ANDROID_BINDER_IPC=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_ANDROID_BINDERFS=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_ANDROID_BINDER_DEVICES="", config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_HIO=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_UBUNTU_HOST=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_QUOTACTL_COMPAT=y, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SHIFT_FS=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SHIFT_FS_POSIX_ACL=y, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_AUFS_FS=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_AUFS_BRANCH_MAX_127=y, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_AUFS_SBILIST=y, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_AUFS_EXPORT=y, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_AUFS_INO_T_64=y, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_AUFS_XATTR=y, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_AUFS_DIRREN=y, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_AUFS_BR_HFSPLUS=y, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_AUFS_BDEV_LOOP=y, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_SECURITY_PERF_EVENTS_RESTRICT=y, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_LOCK_DOWN_IN_SECURE_BOOT=y, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_CHELSIO_IPSEC_INLINE=y, config-5-10: CONFIG_CHELSIO_IPSEC_INLINE=m
config-5-8: CONFIG_CHELSIO_TLS_DEVICE=y, config-5-10: CONFIG_CHELSIO_TLS_DEVICE=m
config-5-8: CONFIG_DMA_VIRT_OPS=y, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_KASAN_STACK=1, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_TORTURE_TEST=m, config-5-10: null
config-5-8: CONFIG_RCU_PERF_TEST=m, config-5-10: null
-----
lines in config-5-10 that differ from config-5-8:
config-5-10: CONFIG_LLD_VERSION=0, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_HAVE_KERNEL_ZSTD=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_HAVE_POSIX_CPU_TIMERS_TASK_WORK=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_POSIX_CPU_TIMERS_TASK_WORK=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_RD_ZSTD=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_LD_ORPHAN_WARN=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_USERMODE_DRIVER=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_SCHEDUTIL=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_KVM_XFER_TO_GUEST_WORK=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_GENERIC_ENTRY=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_SECCOMP=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_HAVE_STATIC_CALL=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_HAVE_STATIC_CALL_INLINE=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_ARCH_WANT_LD_ORPHAN_WARN=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_VMAP_PFN=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_INET_MPTCP_DIAG=m, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_NET_DSA_TAG_RTL4_A=m, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_PCIE_BUS_DEFAULT=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_MTD_NAND_ECC=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_CHELSIO_INLINE_CRYPTO=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_CHELSIO_IPSEC_INLINE=m, config-5-8: CONFIG_CHELSIO_IPSEC_INLINE=y
config-5-10: CONFIG_CHELSIO_TLS_DEVICE=m, config-5-8: CONFIG_CHELSIO_TLS_DEVICE=y
config-5-10: CONFIG_MDIO_DEVRES=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_PCS_XPCS=m, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_MT7663_USB_SDIO_COMMON=m, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_WLAN_VENDOR_MICROCHIP=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_PINCTRL_INTEL=y, config-5-8: CONFIG_PINCTRL_INTEL=m
config-5-10: CONFIG_GPIO_CDEV=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_GPIO_CDEV_V1=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_SND_SOC_SOF_INTEL_SOUNDWIRE_LINK_BASELINE=m, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_SND_SOC_MAX98373_I2C=m, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_USB_ROLE_SWITCH=y, config-5-8: CONFIG_USB_ROLE_SWITCH=m
config-5-10: CONFIG_INFINIBAND_VIRT_DMA=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_VIRTIO_DMA_SHARED_BUFFER=m, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_XEN_UNPOPULATED_ALLOC=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_SOUNDWIRE_GENERIC_ALLOCATION=m, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_BMA400_SPI=m, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_DEV_DAX_HMEM_DEVICES=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_XFS_SUPPORT_V4=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_FUSE_DAX=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_CRYPTO_USER_API_ENABLE_OBSOLETE=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_DECOMPRESS_ZSTD=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_DMA_OPS=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_PLDMFW=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_DEBUG_FS_ALLOW_ALL=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_KGDB_HONOUR_BLOCKLIST=y, config-5-8: null
config-5-10: CONFIG_TRACE_IRQFLAGS_NMI_SUPPORT=y, config-5-8: null
-----
```

Компьтер: Samsung np550xta

Upd.

Вставляя echo 'smth' после каждой строчки в grub.cfg удалось понять, что виснет при вызове "initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.10.16". Некоторые пишут, что стоит выполнить следующую команду "mkinitrd ...", у меня эта команда не найдена, зато найдена "iniramfs".

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить. А зачем понадобилось пересобирать ядро?

Comment: @donRumata в учебных целях

Comment: ну и для общего ознакомления